# Can I manage Azure App Service certificate via third party?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

How do I manage the certificate I purchased via Azure App Service Certificate in GoDaddy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot manage certificate in GoDaddy since you have bought the cert in Azure. And if you want to manage certificate via Azure you can follow the below doc :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site